# json is not translated into Model

Tags: json, flutter, dart

The problem is that when I write DetailsResponseModel.fromJson(responce) nothing is returned (I tried dynamic and everything returned so that's the problem). I made the ResponsModel from QuickType and tried everything there. Did not work out. Are there any options for what could be wrong?

DetailsResponseModel:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final detailsResponseModel = detailsResponseModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

DetailsResponseModel detailsResponseModelFromJson(String str) => DetailsResponseModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String detailsResponseModelToJson(DetailsResponseModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class DetailsResponseModel {
    DetailsResponseModel({
        required this.pkId,
        required this.status,
        required this.dateBegin,
        this.dateEnd,
        required this.usersTotal,
        required this.usersActive,
        required this.moneyTotal,
        required this.moneyRest,
        required this.incomeRate,
        required this.chart,
    });

    int pkId;
    String status;
    DateTime dateBegin;
    DateTime? dateEnd;
    int usersTotal;
    int usersActive;
    double moneyTotal;
    int moneyRest;
    double incomeRate;
    List<Chart> chart;

    factory DetailsResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DetailsResponseModel(
        pkId: json["pk_id"],
        status: json["status"],
        dateBegin: DateTime.parse(json["date_begin"]),
        dateEnd: json["date_end"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["date_end"]),
        usersTotal: json["users_total"],
        usersActive: json["users_active"],
        moneyTotal: json["money_total"]?.toDouble(),
        moneyRest: json["money_rest"],
        incomeRate: json["income_rate"]?.toDouble(),
        chart: List<Chart>.from(json["chart"].map((x) => Chart.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "pk_id": pkId,
        "status": status,
        "date_begin": dateBegin.toIso8601String(),
        "date_end": dateEnd?.toIso8601String(),
        "users_total": usersTotal,
        "users_active": usersActive,
        "money_total": moneyTotal,
        "money_rest": moneyRest,
        "income_rate": incomeRate,
        "chart": List<dynamic>.from(chart.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Chart {
    Chart({
        required this.datetime,
        required this.value,
    });

    DateTime datetime;
    double value;

    factory Chart.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Chart(
        datetime: DateTime.parse(json["datetime"]),
        value: json["value"]?.toDouble(),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "datetime": datetime.toIso8601String(),
        "value": value,
    };
}
```

json:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "pk_id": 5,
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "date_begin": "2023-03-25T00:00:00Z",
    "date_end": null,
    "users_total": 6,
    "users_active": 6,
    "money_total": 15.0,
    "money_rest": 13.0,
    "income_rate": 1.5,
    "chart": [
        {
            "datetime": "2023-04-12T16:43:45Z",
            "value": 7.0
        },
        {
            "datetime": "2023-04-04T16:44:27Z",
            "value": 3.0
        }
    ]
}
```

dataSource:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';

import '../../../core/shared/http.dart';
import '../../models/response/details_by_id_response_model.dart';

abstract class DetailsByIdRemoteDataSource {
  Future<DetailsResponseModel> getDetailsById({required int scenario});

}

@LazySingleton(as: DetailsByIdRemoteDataSource)
class DetailsByIdRemoteDataSourceImpl implements DetailsByIdRemoteDataSource {
  final Http http;
  const DetailsByIdRemoteDataSourceImpl({
    required this.http,
  });

  @override
  Future<DetailsResponseModel> getDetailsById(
      {required int scenario}) async {
    final response = await http.get(
      '/scenarioinfo?scenario_id=$scenario&pk_id=3',
    );

    return DetailsResponseModel.fromJson(response);
  }
}
```

Jason himself returns to the debug so everything is fine with the get request. I tried to put everything on datetime, it just didn't work. It's been 3 days with this problem.

Comment: `return DetailsResponseModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));`

Comment: I already did this in http class

Comment: please use `try{} catch()` when you call the api. so you will know the error. will be more help if we know the actuall error

Comment: I have a separate HTTP class in which I registered it. There are no errors during the request, only in the translation of json into Model

Comment: thats why i suggest you to use `try catch`.not only while call api, use `try catch` where you want to debug.  must be something wrong while  serialization . and you need to catch and print the error

Comment: I got you, thank you, I'll try it now

Comment: I/flutter ( 4676): type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' there is error

Comment: You may have to decode the response as suggested to get the object .